# Is there a way to do SQL queries against MS Access but outside of the program?

Tags: database, ms-access, data-analysis

I have a case where I want to make tool for people in my company to use. It's a simple tool to import log-type data into a database, that tool should sort data and do some operations on it (like calculate difference between time based on previous record etc). But I'm restricted by corporation security programs so I have to stick to office and tools that don't require installing anything new.

I made access which do the job, but due to bad performance on even small portion of data I have to look for something else. Also Excel is not an answer due to limitation in number of lines.

Is there a way to make some tool that will use Access as database, but will do operations on data outside of it, and the result will be returned to access as completed table? For what should I look to make such tool?

Comment: _but due to bad performance_ - unless you are doing extremely complicated manipulation of data before importing, no other tool will be faster. Perhaps you are using sub-optimal methods ...

Comment: Not really complicated, just the difference in time between two records as we discussed in my older question, and thanks to your help worked ;)  But my point is that I tried it on small portion of data ~300k records and access just can't handle this.

Comment: Oh, but at that time you had _text times_, which means that each and every record must be converted, and so must all records to compare to. This is doomed to be slow. But steps can be taken to beef it up by a magnitude. Too much to post here, indeed having no representative data.

Comment: So maybe outside of  main question. How to make sure I'm importing time from txt file to access right? To not have to convert it from text times to real times? Or maybe should I make another query to convert it and run it before compering?

Comment: The common method is to link the text file _as is_. Then create a simple select query that filter and convert as desired to optimum field data types. Use this query as source to import to a temporary or the final table - you would need a temp table. Modify this to have proper indexing on relevant fields (IDs and your dates). Finally, for more complicated handling, run either code to loop the table and append records to the final table; or, for a less complicated case, run an append query. This run very fast - 300k records isn't that much.

Answer (score 1):

Vb.net is a Microsoft language that is easy to learn, you can create an application graphically, you can connect it to access DB. it will really help you in your situation. I'm personally using it to create access data managing apps.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use any client that can connect through the ODBC standard interface to the underlying tables/database.

I have just been using RazorSQL to help me get my SQL right with syntax highlighting and autocomplete (though these are not always right)

May not be quite the answer readers are looking for, but this question came up in the search when I was looking for a way to SQL-query an access database file from outside the Access program.